# IE Explorer Does Not Render SVG Properly

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Please visit http://www.lab.zenofwp.com/california-protection/ with chrome and firefox and note how perfectly these 2 browsers render the Cal. map. Now visit the url with IE Explorer and compare.  The borders between counties is very thick and the text in the legend in the upper right does not display. Any ideas as to how I can make IE Explorer display this properly?  Thanks

Comment: You should put the code (or better yet a [mcve]) in the question. If the site changes then the question becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The map is being handled by the mapsvg plugin for WordPress.  The map plugin's jQuery file adjusts the stroke thickness for IE Explorer.  However its code to determine if the browser is IE Explorer or not is faulty and I patched.